# Objects with vector not properly setting info in the vector (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, polymorphism

Heyo! I'm fairly new to C++ but have some background in coding, so a simpler explanation would be fantastic. I have been working on a fairly complicated program and an issue appeared. I have an object called "Tile" being made in a vector.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ySize; i++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= xSize; i2++) {
        tiles.push_back(make_unique <Tile>());
        tiles[i*xSize + i2]->set_height(fn.GetNoise(i2, i));
        tiles[i*xSize + i2]->set_xPos(i2);
        tiles[i*xSize + i2]->set_yPos(i);
        tiles[i*xSize + i2]->update_tile();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ideally the tiles are generated in a grid manner. Within the tile objects is a vector called "goods".

```
vector unique_ptr<Good*> goods;
```

These goods are added through the double for loop here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ySize; i++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= xSize; i2++) {
        if (tiles[i*xSize + i2]->get_rainfall() >= 0.1 && tiles[i*xSize + i2]->get_height() >= -0.2 && tiles[i*xSize + i2]->get_height() <= 0.55 && fn.GetNoise(i2, i) < 0) {
            tiles[i*xSize + i2]->add_available_good(1001, (fn.GetNoise(i, i2)*500+214));
            tiles[i*xSize + i2]->update_tile();
        }
    }
}
```

This vector will store child classes of class Good through here:

```
void Tile::add_available_good(short unsigned int g, short int a) {
//Adds good based on GoodID
switch (g) {
case 1001:
    goods.emplace_back(new Tree(a));
    break;
case 1002:

    break;
default:

    break;
}
```

}

The problem that has appeared is that whenever I call tiles

```
[i*xSize + i2]->add_available_good(num, num);
```

Something goes funny. The size of vector Goods on any given tile becomes the number of goods added to all of the tiles. In other words it appears the goods vector is shared between all of the tile objects. How do I fix this?

I am terrible at explaining things but I tried my best. Thank you in advance!

Tile class definition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <random>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

//Misc inclusions
#include "Building.h"
#include "Good.h"

class Tile
{
public:
Tile();
void print_tile();
void set_tile_symbol(char);
char get_tile_symbol();
void set_tile_color(float);
float get_tile_color();
void add_building(short unsigned int);
void set_height(double);
double get_height();
void update_tile();
void add_available_good(short unsigned int, short int);
void set_rainfall(double);
double get_rainfall();
void set_xPos(int);
void set_yPos(int);
short unsigned int get_good(short unsigned int);
short unsigned int get_good_weight(short unsigned int);
void print_good();
~Tile();
private:

char symbol;
int xpos;
int ypos;
float color;
short unsigned int usableSpace = 36;
double height = 0;
int pop = 0;
bool hasPop = 0;
double rainfall = 0;
};
```

Good class definition:

```
class Good
{
public:
Good();
void set_weight(double);
void change_weight(double);
double get_weight();        
void set_value(double);
double get_value();
void change_value(double);
short unsigned int get_symbolShowsAt();
char get_symbol();
short unsigned int get_goodID();
~Good();    
protected:
double weight;
short unsigned int reqFunction[5];
short unsigned int reqGoodID[5];
short unsigned int goodWeight[5];
double value = 1;
short unsigned int goodID = 1000;
short unsigned int functionID = 4000;
bool hasSymbol = 0;
short unsigned int symbolShowsAt = 100;
char symbol = 0;
int size = 1;
};
struct Tree : public Good { Tree(short unsigned int w); };
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve].  Enough code that someone could compile it and reproduce your problem (and no more).  Right now you're missing some important things, like the definition of `Tile` and a syntactically valid definition of `goods`.

Comment: I would but it is a few hundred lines of code total. Ill add the class definitions of Tile and Good though, thanks for the advice

Comment: Please read the link.  A few hundred lines fails the "Minimal" part of "[mcve]".  Strip your code down to a minimal example that compiles and demonstrates your problem.

Comment: class Tile does not contain the goods vector you speak of. At least not according to what you just posted. if its a global variable that would explain your problem

Comment: vector <unique_ptr<Good*>> goods; is within the implementation of Tile

Comment: If you want one of those vectors per `Tile` it needs to be declared as a member variable, which at the moment it isnt.

Comment: Thank you! I assume that will fix it. And yes it was a global variable. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why would you have a unique_ptr of a pointer ?

Comment: Been trying to figure out why this wasn't working all day, tried everything, is there something I should rather be using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the global vector to be a member.